# chai check if array of strings has one with a subset string

Tags: chai

I have an array of strings `['abc,'def','ghi','jkl']`

I have string B equal to `'j'`.

I want to check if any element in the array has string B as a substring with `chai`

Is this possible? I can't seem to figure out how to use the `.any` in chai to test each element in the array matches

I've tried a number of things including but not limited to:

```
expect(array).any.to.contain(string)
expect(array).any.to.have.string(string)
expect(array)to.have.any.string(string)
```

Is there an elegant way to test this?

Comment: if it is for any element of the array, I think you will need to iterate over it.

Answer (score 10):

There are a number of ways to achieve this, depending on what your search criteria are.

If you're looking for a single character, as in the example, you could join the array strings then check for the resulting string containing the character.  This method may not work well if you're looking for multi-character strings as you could pick up the end of one entry and be beginning of the next.  If you know your string will never contain a given character, then you could introduce a delimiter.

```
expect(array.join()).to.include(single_character);
// or assuming your array will never include pipe (|)
expect(array.join('|').to.include(string);
```

On failure, would output:

```
Should find substrings:
 AssertionError: expected 'abc|def|ghi|jkl' to include 'jl'
```

Alternatively you could search the array using the .some() method and assert that the result is true.

```
expect(array.some(x => x.includes(string))).to.be.true;
```

On failure, would output:

```
Should find substrings:

  AssertionError: expected false to be true
  + expected - actual

  -false
  +true
```

A custom error message could help understanding:

```
expect(
  array.some(x => x.includes(string)),
  `expected ${array} to include nested string ${string}`,
).to.be.true;
```

On failure, would output:

```
Should find substrings:

  expected abc,def,ghi,jkl to include nested string jl
  + expected - actual

  -false
  +true
```

Or use a `satisfy` check:

```
const array = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl'];
const string = 'jl';
expect(array).to.satisfy(array => array.some(item => item.includes(string)));
```

On failure, would output:

```
Should find substrings:

  AssertionError: expected [ 'abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl' ] to satisfy [Function]
  + expected - actual

  -false
  +true
```

Comment: Just a small note, proposed alternative method will result in error message being "expected false to be true" which is less than ideal

Comment: @SerhiiHrynko thanks for the nudge. Added some more examples that may help address your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Came up with this helper function for assertions by reading some of the previous answers:

```js
/**
 * Tests the schema errors and evaluates if a substring is contained within the errors.
 * @param validData - Data to be validated.
 * @param substring - Evaluated substring.
 * @param message - Mocha assertion message.
 * @returns {void}
 */
function expectSchemaErrorsToContain(validData: any, substrings: readonly string[], message?: string): void {
  const errors: string[] = getSchemaErrors(validData, dataSchema);
  const stringifiedErrors = JSON.stringify(errors, null, 0);
  for (const substring of substrings) {
    expect(stringifiedErrors, message).to.include(substring);
  }
  // Non-substring alternative:
  // expect(getSchemaErrors(validData, dataSchema)).to.include.members(substrings);
}
```

And here's a quick example:

```js
_.set(validData, 'db', {});
expectSchemaErrorsToContain(validData, [
  '/db/connectionString is a required field',
  '/db/dbName is a required field',
]);
```

You might want to adapt it to your code.

Answer (score -1):

You may want to use the `include` method:

```
expect(array).to.include('string')
```

Comment: this answer is incorrect as this will fail if element is not equal to expected 'string' value in the example code. OP asks for a subset that mean ['some_string', 'not match', 'not match neither'] should pass the assertion. And your code will fail it.